# Arduino: Measuring Current, Voltage + using the 5V and GND pins

Tags: arduino, ground

I am new to the Arduino world and I don't wanna destory my brand-new Arduino, so I am asking here first. Basically what I am doing for a school project is creating a circuit that will measure current and voltage of a solar panel while increasing the resistance of the circuit.
I am using a ACS715 for measuring current and a MCP4142 as an digital resistor. I am also using a basic voltage divider for measuring voltage.
Maybe my bad designed paint scheme would help:
[image: bad and probably wrong circuit]

Will that work like I painted it here or will I have a short circuit and destory my Arduino? My problem is that I put P0W also on ground by using my voltage divider (the whole line from the 30k resistor to P0W is basically grounded by that). So I think there's a problem if Vss and P0W of the MCP4142 are both on the same ground, or am I wrong?

It might sound dumb, but I am just a dumb student, so please bear with me :D

Edit:

To be more clear about what I want to achieve. I want to increase the overall resistance of my circuit and measure the voltage/current that my solar panel has using that resistance to create like R-U-diagramms.

Comment: Yep, its likely useful to post a block diagram with a language that not all will understand.

Comment: The only part that's likely to be destroyed is the poor little MCP4142. When you set it to a low-ish resistance it'll start trying to sink a lot of current, causing it to dissipate a lot of power as heat. You'd probably be better off replacing it with a MOSFET mounted to a heatsink and driving the MOSFET with a PWM signal from your Arduino.

Comment: I see a problem: top of 30 ohm resistor to Arduino GND (OK sofar) then connected to P0W8 of Arduino: that is not OK.

Comment: I'd also probably reduce the resistance values in your voltage divider by a factor of 10 and put a capacitor from A1 to Gnd. (assuming you have 30k and 120k resistors, not 30ohm and 120ohm)

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm sorry, but it doesn't really add any information. It just says "current sensor" for the ACS715 and "digital resistor" for the MCP4142

Comment: @brhans Would it also be possible to cool the MCP4142? If I power drive a MOSFET with PWM, why would that create a resistor? I want to slowly increase my resistance in the circuit and I don't really know how a MOSFET would benefit me there..

Comment: @FakeMoustache That's what I thought too! But how would I fix that? I mean, the top of the resistor needs to be connected to GND to measure the voltage. But P0W also needs to be connected to the minus pole of the solar module which needs to be connected to the resistor. I don't know how to fix that as it also seems necessary to be like it is currently :/

Comment: The MCP4142 isn't really made to be able to dissipate much power. Its 'Absolute Maximum' rating in the datasheet is 400mW, but that's more of a stress rating above which the part will be damaged. Its not intended to operate properly at that level, and its package is not designed to be able to dissipate the heat effectively.

Comment: If you low-pass filter the PWM into something that more resembles a variable DC voltage and use that to control the MOSFET, then your MOSFET *sort-of* becomes a variable resistor.

Comment: @brhans I know you can use a MOSFET to control the voltage, but that's not what I want to achieve. I want to keep my original voltage from my solar module and see how it changes when the overall resistance of the circuit increases. For example to get a diagram where R is on the X-axis and U on the y-axis. I don't want to build a voltage regulator with that.

Comment: @Maximilian Böther The MOSFEET in the mentioned scenario will not act as a voltage regulator. It will act as a resistor.  Take a look at the animations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-effect_transistor#FET_operation). The channel acts as a sort-of Ohmic contact and basically only acts as a resistor.

Even a real rheostat will act the same way as a MOSFET. Keep in mind that you're measuring the voltage directly across the module. You (as far as voltage measurement is concerned) are not really interested in what's happening afterwards.

Comment: @Maximilian Böther Also be sure to read up a bit on how MOSFETs work. From your comments I get an idea that it's not really clear to you.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Yes, you are right, I don't really know much about MOSFETs... That's why I wanted to stick with a digital rheostat... Is there a digital rheostat that can handle up to 10 W? I am really having a hard time finding one and I am too dumb to do the MOSFET stuff <.<

Comment: On the other side, for low power amounts that the MCP4142 can handle, would my circuit work? I am still not sure about the GND-thing @FakeMoustache mentioned (and I also mentioned it in my post)

Comment: @Maximilian Böther I'm pretty sure that there aren't. You might be able to find a "motorized rheostat", which is, as its name implies a classical analog rheostat with a motor attached that you might be able to drive.

Comment: That's what I feared... But would the circuit above work for low-power usage or would the GND cause a problem (see my last post for that)

Comment: @Maximilian Böther I don't see an issue with that at the moment, but that doesn't mean that there isn't one, it could be that it's just past my bedtime. I mean, datasheet for the poti says `Voltage on all other pins (PxA, PxW, PxB, and SDO) with respect to V_SS -0.3V to V DD + 0.3V` so grounding it should be fine from the potentiometer's point of view, if you can maintain the maximum current through the potentiometer.